# display the array which meets only this condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, php-5.3

i have a multidimensional array, and iam looping inside to get the sub-arrays:
so i have a sub-array lie this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 2.5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 7.01,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 4.167,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 1.267,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 3.54,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 2.04,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.673,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 8.546,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'norm_value' => 0.0,
  ),
)
```

So from the above set of arrays, i want remove the complete array which has atleast one non-zero value or all zero values, from the above case i want to remove the complete second array(this has only one non-zero value) and third array(this has all zero values) array , other two (first and last) arrays are to be displayed as it is.

i tried this pie of code, but didnt work for me:

```
array_filter(array_column($array, 'norm_value'),function($n){
    return ( count ($n > 0) <= 1) ;
});
```

please let me know if i am missing anything here or any syntax issues to fix this problem
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Can you share a var_export() of you array?

Comment: @vivek_23, here is the data after var_export(): https://tmpfiles.org/download/40934/sampleArray.php

Comment: The link gives me a file not found message. Can you just post the var_export() in your post by editing?

Comment: @vivek_23 have edited the post with  var_export() data result

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now. So, remove all arrays which have either all zero values or all values zero with one non zero value. Am I correct?

Comment: exactly, you are right

Comment: Ok, l will try.

Comment: @vivek_23 any chances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would loop over each subarray and count how many `norm_value` has `0.0`. If the count matches the `size` or `size-1`, then we unset that index.

```
$epsilon = 0.00001;

foreach($arr as $index => $subarray){
    $count = 0;
    foreach($subarray as $norm_data){
        if(abs($norm_data['norm_value'] - 0.0) < $epsilon) $count++;
    }

    if($count === count($subarray) || $count == count($subarray)-1){
        unset($arr[$index]);
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/futQ8